# POST is never performed after social login with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm using [angularx-social-login](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) to connect via Facebook and Google with my Angular 6 app.

It works great, I can get the user data from FB and Google, but then I want to make a POST to my backend, and the POST is never made in Chrome Console.

Here is my code:

in login.component.ts

```
signInWithFB(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.auth.socialLogin(user);
    });
  }
```

in authentication.service.ts

```
socialLogin(userData) {
    const user = new User(userData.name);
    user.email = userData.email;
    user.firstname = userData.firstName;
    user.lastname = userData.lastName;
    user.avatar = userData.photoUrl;
    user.provider = userData.provider;
    user.token = userData.authToken;
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/auth/socialLogin', user, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return res;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
      );
  }
```

I can see the result of:

```
     console.log(user);
```

but the post is never made, how is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call .subscribe on the  Observable returned from post

```
this.auth.socialLogin(user).subscribe((data) => {

});
```

Comment: it seems to be working, but now, it is making 2 calls... I will update my code

Comment: Tx for the help !